# Correct way to use multiple itemtypes in Microdata

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

See http://microdatagenerator.org/ for example.

What is the standardized way of, for example, declaring that my page is about a `LocalBusiness` which is also an `AutomotiveBusiness`? And where is the standards document that specifies this definitively?

Answer (score 5):

The [W3C Microdata](https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/) specification (currently a Working Draft) says about the [`itemtype` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/WD-microdata-20180426/#dfn-itemtype):

> The `itemtype` attribute, if specified, must have a value that is an unordered set of unique space-separated tokens that are case-sensitive, each of which is a valid absolute URL, and all of which are in the same vocabulary. The attribute's value must have at least one token.

#### Multiple types from the same vocabulary

So you can specify multiple item types in an `itemtype` attribute ***if*** they are all from the same vocabulary (e.g. Schema.org):

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/HotelRoom http://schema.org/Offer">
 <!-- an MTE (multi-typed entity) 
      with the types 'HotelRoom' and 'Offer' -->
</article>
```

In your case it would typically not be necessary to provide both types, as [`AutomotiveBusiness`](https://schema.org/AutomotiveBusiness) inherits from [`LocalBusiness`](https://schema.org/LocalBusiness) (i.e., every `AutomotiveBusiness` is also a `LocalBusiness`).

#### Multiple types from different vocabularies

If you want to provide types from multiple vocabularies, you can use Schema.org’s [`additionalType`](https://schema.org/additionalType) property:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AutomotiveBusiness">
  <link itemprop="additionalType" href="http://www.productontology.org/id/Automobile_repair_shop" />
 <!-- an MTE (multi-typed entity) 
      with the Schema.org type 'AutomotiveBusiness' 
      an an additional PTO type 'Automobile_repair_shop' -->
</article>
```

#### Multiple items with the same `itemid` value

You can also provide separate items (each with its own `itemscope`) and give them the same `itemid` value, thereby conveying that they are about the same thing:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/HotelRoom" itemid="/rooms/42#this">
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemid="/rooms/42#this">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@unor is right. 
As of now, this is not possible with HTML5 Microdata to use itemtypes from different vocabs. There is a discussion however [1] on how to enable this.

[1] http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/additionalTypeProposal